# What is the proper drcsim-1.1 setup for the moving joints by animation tutorial

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In going through the tutorials again, I've noticed that the wiki is not up to date for the controller changes to drcsim-1.1.  Specifically, the drc_robot_position_controller.launch must be used in place of drc_robot.launch for earlier tutorials.  (I made note of this on the first tutorial wiki.)

I tried the [http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/ros\_animated\_robot](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/drcsim/ros%5C_animated%5C_robot) tutorial, but it does not appear to work either.

I haven't been able to back out the changes to world that would have changed the plugin behavior yet; has anyone gotten this to work with the drcsim-1.1 release?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/330/what-is-the-proper-drcsim-1.1-setup-for-the-moving-joints-by-animation-tutorial/) by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 298 on 2012-11-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-11-30**:
That vote should put you over the karma threshold for voting. Do what I did and use your limited votes on the best answers and question to help seed healthy community participation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The issues have been resolved with the 1.3 release of drcsim.  The tutorials have been updated to reflect the appropriate changes

---

Originally posted by [dcconner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/47/dcconner/) with karma: 298 on 2013-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0